# Cant figure out where IMG is

Tags: html, css

Hi i'm working with a new template, and there's a main image on the landing page.

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbBoX.png)

It's the photo behind the main text. I cannot figure out where the img source is.
I don't see it in the HTML. I just would like to find where this stock image is and swap my new image into its place.

I'm pretty sure the following code is where it should be:

```
  <!-- home -->
  <section aria-label="home" class="mainbg" id="home">

    <!-- intro -->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="overlay-main v-align">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-11">

        <h1 class="onStep" data-animation="animbouncefall" data-time="300">LOUIS WALLACE CONSTRUCTION</h1>
        <div class="onStep" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-time="600" id="slidertext">
          <h3 class="main-text">We Build Your Dream</h3>
          <h3 class="main-text">We Are Passionate</h3>
          <h3 class="main-text">We Are Capable</h3>
        </div>
        <p class="onStep" data-animation="animbouncefall" data-time="900">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet eas malesuada leo. Vestibulum eros magna volutpat at facilisis cursus, tempus etex Vestibulum pellentesque et dolor sit amet. Pellentesque eu enim nec nibh convallis suscipit. Morbi interdum dignissim metus dignissim gravida.
        </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- intro end -->
  </section>
  <!-- home end -->
```

Is there some way it could be in the css?

Edit: when I inspect it, first of all I'm not entirely sure which one is for the image. In any case, when I select what I think is the right element, the styles area don't point to any img tag.

Comment: Yes images can be in CSS eg as a background or pseudo element. Open up developer tools and inspect the image. It will show you where it is.

Comment: i know how to right click and get to the inspection page, but i dont know where to look. Im in the styles section

Comment: Please use answers for answers. If needed, [edit] your question to include any further information.

Comment: seems like it's an image from a slideshow. It could be in CSS as background-image or somewhere in the slideshow js file

Comment: Right click on the page, click 'view page source', then ctrl+f to find the image. 

Check the javascript too.

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely being displayed as a background using the mainbg css class. Can you look in your stylesheet for mainbg?

Comment: maybe this is a good time to ask this too. Is there some efficient way of locating a css class? Is there some sort of tool? Everything ive tried is completely ineffective.

Comment: You should just be able to look in your CSS file. Ctrl f on windows and search for the class. Cmd f on mac.